# What does "Made by <country>" mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrase-meaning

I have recently encountered a car advert from the manufacturer Volvo Cars with the tagline "made by Sweden" instead of more usual "made in Sweden", so I'm wondering what it's supposed to mean. I have some possible interpretations:

1. (most probable) they want to indicate not only manufacture location, but emphasize that the car is a product of every Swede and embodies some deeply Swedish values
2. the car is manufactured by the state (not true, as the automaker is owned by Chinese company)
3. the car is not actually made in Sweden, so they could not use "made in Sweden" phrase (like "designed in California, made in China") - quite unlikely, at least according to Wikipedia the car in question is manufactured in Sweden

Comment: You should always include as much context as possible. Was this ad by [Volvo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volvo_Cars)? At first I guessed it was a mistake, but seeing as it was from Volvo, it seems deliberate--unless this is some peculiar BrE usage.

Comment: As this question is about phrase used in commercial campaign, I was unsure if it was appropriate to include actual adverts here. Yes, it's about Volvo (I think it was rather easy to guess;))

Comment: I suspect it's an error. After all, the Electrolux vacuum cleaner company's headquarters are in Sweden, and back in the day they came up with the slogan "Nothing sucks like an Electrolux." This earned them a Nova award, an award given in memory of the GM campaign in Mexico for the Chevy Nova. As your name suggests you already know, no va in Spanish means "doesn't go."

Answer (score 6):

My two cents:

It is a half slogan you are writing. The original one is:

> Volvo - Made by People 
>  Made by Sweden.

They say that the best cars are not built by Americans, Koreans, Swedes or Italians. They are made *by all of them, together.*

Vovlo says that since 50s, the company has been importing brilliant brains from all over the world to Sweden. The company believes that diversity sparks creativity pushing innovation further.

Volvo is ***made by people*** from all over the world. But, they *gather in Sweden*, so it's made *by Sweden.*

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUDx6NEqdJQ

---

Another possibility:

By using 'by,' we make the country active. Calling Volvo cars are made **in** Sweden shows that Sweden is merely a place where the cars are made. If we replace it with 'by,' it shows 'efforts', and it has an emotional touch.

> Volvo cars: made **in** Sweden - Sweden is some place where cars are made 
>  Volvo cars: made **by** Sweden - Sweden makes its best efforts to make the cars.